# pycharm ctrl+v copies the item in console instead paste when highlighted

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, copy-paste

This has been a very annoying problem for me and I couldn't find any keymaps or settings that could cause this behavior.

### Setup:

1. Pycharm Professional 2018.1 installed on redhat linux
2. I remote into the linux machine using mobaX and launch pycharm with window forwarding

### Scenario 1:

I open a browser on windows, copy some text, go to editor or console, paste it somewhere without highlighting any text, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, it pastes fine

### Scenario 2:

I open a browser on windows, copy some text, go to editor or console, highlight some text there, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> in attempt to replace the highlighted text with what's in my clipboard. The text didn't change. I leave pycharm and paste somewhere else, the text in clipboard has now become the text I highlighted.

Edit:
ok I just realized this: as soon as I highlight the text, it gets copied...I've turned this feature off for terminal, but couldn't find a global settings for the editor etc. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: it's caused by the copy-on-select setting of my linux system. To turn it off, go to mobax-settings-configurations-x11-clipboard-disable 'copy on select'